# How to replace the ',' between two numbers like X,X% into X.X% in all the dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas data frame like below. Column name is 'ingredients_text'
[image]

Now I want to replace all the values like 5,5% to 5.5% in this column in all the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["ingredients_text"] = df["ingredients_text"].str.replace(r'\b(\d+),(\d+)%', r'\1.\2%')
```

The pattern `\b(\d+),(\d+)%` matches in the first and second capture groups, respectively, the whole number and decimal component of the percentage.  Then we replace with `\1.\2%`, replacing the comma with dot.

Comment: thanks it works but the % has disappeared !

Comment: @Yoss Sorry...forgot to also include that in the replacement.